# Dynamically naming tables in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a table in HTML which will have 8 columns and 150 rows.Basic structure of it will be like this http://s8.postimg.org/kktmcvq05/table.png  But here there are only 13 rows.I want to create 150 rows and difference between them will be of sector number like in above image.I don't want to manually write all sectors but want to generate them using some php code or javascript code is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, perfectly possible HTH. - [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Doing some research and making an attempt would be a good start. If you have problems with your attempt, then come back and seek help. We debug your source code and explain why your current source code isn't working as intended, then offer solution(s) if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy one row from your HTML and output this row with PHP in a loop like this:

```
// repeat this loop 150 times
for($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++) {
    // outputs one row
    echo "<tr>";

    // outputs rowName with a number from 0 to 149
    echo "<td>Noida Sector $i</td>";

    // outputs your eight checkboxes
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";

    // end tag for this row
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Replace the TDs with your own TDs from your HTML code.

If you want to count from 1 to 150 instead of 0 to 149, you can just change the loop-definition to `$i = 1; $i <= 150; $i++`

Comment: I would recommend you give more detail with your answer. No indication of what language is used here and no explanation how this for loop works. When a user posts a question with no source code and you choose to answer, its best to explain as much as possible. You can't assume people know how this works just by looking at it.

Comment: I didn't think about it ... changed it now, so it should be clear

Comment: Many people google problems so making your answer clear and detailed can help multiple people with the same/similar issue.